# Swift create a common extension for UIButton and UIView Color change

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to creating multiple `buttons`. Here, each buttons placed on separate UIView. This buttons working like a single section based on selection Its title color and `UIView` color I am changing in each button acton method. Here, I need to create a common extension for all button title and UIView color change. Once, button click need to pass the value to extension or a function to change the colors for `selection` button. This is I am trying for reducing the code duplication and LOC.

`NOTE:` Below I posted only one button code but I have many button. I want to make it common class and pass the value to change the colors. How to achieve this?

**First Button Action**

```
 @IBAction func firstButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        self.onetimeView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.184337255, green: 0.683529412, blue: 0.976475882, alpha: 1)
        self.dailyView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.weeklyView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.fiftydaysView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.monthlyView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

        self.onetimeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.selectedColor, for: .normal)
        self.dailyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
        self.weeklyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
        self.fiftydaysButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
        self.monthlyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
    }

@IBAction func secondButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
       self.onetimeView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
       self.dailyView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.184337255, green: 0.683529412, blue: 0.976475882, alpha: 1)
       self.weeklyView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
       self.fiftydaysView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
       self.monthlyView.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

       self.onetimeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
       self.dailyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.selectedColor, for: .normal)
       self.weeklyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
       self.fiftydaysButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
       self.monthlyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
    }

extension UIColor {
    static var selectedColor = UIColor.init(red: 47/255, green: 174/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
    static var disabledColor = UIColor.init(red: 170/255, green: 170/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass like:

class PrimaryButton: UIButton {
}

Comment: Sorry, it won't help me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Store your buttons and views in some data structure and iterate over it. Create a function that will set `selectedColor` on views passed as an argument and `disabledColor` on the rest.

```
typealias Section = (UIButton, UIView)

let sections: [Section] = [
    (button: onetimeButton, view: onetimeView),
    (button: dailyButton, view: dailyView),
    (button: weeklyButton, view: weeklyView),
    (button: fiftydaysButton, view: fiftydaysView),
    (button: monthlyButton, view: monthlyView),
]

func select(_ section: Section) {
    sections.forEach { (section) in
        section.0.setTitleColor(UIColor.disabledColor, for: .normal)
        section.1.backgroundColor = UIColor.disabledColor
    }

    section.0.setTitleColor(UIColor.selectedColor, for: .normal)
    section.1.backgroundColor = UIColor.selectedColor
}

// in UIButton click call
select((onetimeButton, onetimeView))
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. Btw it is throwing error crash`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Demo.ModernViewController select:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'`